# How do executables use POSIX to keep compatibility between different UNIX systems?

Tags: linux, posix

In my understanding, POSIX only specifies a set of APIs that the OS needs to provide, but it doesn’t specify the implementation detail, specifically the assembly level compatibility. For example, on x86, you need to use a syscall to get the POSIX API:

```
1. set `eax` to the syscall number
2. set syscall arguments
3. call int 0x80
```

But this process can vary a lot depending on:

1. UNIX OS: different OS can have a different mapping from syscall number to POSIX API
2. architecture: X86/arm have different instructions to call `int 0x80`

So I think that POSIX does its job by keeping the API conversion for the POSIX library in different OS. e.g. `glibc.so`:

The POSIX API is provided as glibc symbols. Every time the executable calls the POSIX API, it finds the symbol in every OS's `glibc.so` and there is no need to call int 0x80 directly in the executable.

So my question is:

1. is my understanding correct?
2. besides `glibc.so`, are there any other libraries which act like `glibc.so` but in different UNIX OS?

Comment: `glibc` is one, you have `musl` for another popular Linux libc, then for macOS see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240639/2072269

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) doesn’t specify binary interfaces, so you can’t build a “POSIX” binary and run it on different POSIX-style operating systems. POSIX doesn’t even care about system calls; it defines functions, and it doesn’t matter where those functions end up implemented.

In practice, on Linux and other POSIX-style systems, the functions are implemented in a “C library”, as you mention. But there isn’t even a POSIX-defined way for binaries to call those functions; POSIX for C programs is mostly relevant when writing and compiling programs, and when considering the behaviour of system interfaces at runtime, but not as far as *how* those interfaces are accessed. [The `c99` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/c99.html) to run a compiler is specified, so being able to take C source and turn it into a binary is a requirement in POSIX, but the details of that binary are system-specific. (Binary interfaces on Linux follow the specification known as [the System V ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/4500798), with various architecture-specific extensions.)

There are other C libraries. Each platform provides its own, and some platforms have several. On Linux, there is [the GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), but also [musl](https://musl.libc.org/).

Note too that the C library isn’t only used for C programs; on POSIX-style systems, most compilers and interpreters end up using it. (Notable exceptions include Go binaries which implement their own interfaces to the kernel user-space API.)

Comment: Note that POSIX specifies a [c99 utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/c99.html) and how to use it to get an executable that can make use of the POSIX interface. See also the *It is unspecified whether the libraries libc.a, libl.a, libm.a, libpthread.a, librt.a, libtrace.a, libxnet.a, or liby.a exist as regular files. The implementation may accept as -l option-arguments names of objects that do not exist as regular files* about its `-l c`/`-l l`/`-l m`...